# Using Rauch comparison theorem to get an estimation of two metric.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Picture bottom is from the section 8.4 of Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow.  I use the following Rauch theorem

> > [image]
> > [image]

From the $|Rm|\le 1$, I have sectional curavture $ K \le 1$. Therefore, I have
$$
|Y|'' + |Y| \ge 0
$$
I have
$$
|Y| \ge C_1 \sin t + C_2 \cos t
$$
for some constants $C_1, C_2$. But then, I don't know how to get the red line of picture below.

> > [image]